# Angular 2 - How to enable / disable contenteditable via click?

Tags: angular

I would like to disable and enable the edit mode on the element I click
I have a loop that runs through and displays me widgets.

```
                <div *ngFor="let widget of container.widgets; let j = index" 
                     class="item-column list-group-item " 
                     dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="j" 
                     [dragEnabled]="!dragOperation" 
                     (onDragEnter)="onDragEnter(widget, $event)" 

                     (dblclick)="eventEmitDoubleClick(widget, container.widgets)"
             contenteditable="false"
                     >

                         <div class="item-item" > 
                             {{widget.name}}
                        </div>


                </div>
```

My click event

```
dragOperation: Boolean = false;
contenteditable: Boolean = false;
eventEmitDoubleClick(widget, containerWidgets) {

        if(this.dragOperation){
          this.dragOperation = false;
          this.contenteditable = true;
        }else{ 
         this.dragOperation = true;
          this.contenteditable = false;
        }   

    }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: What's happening now?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ... [contenteditable]="contenteditable"
```

Comment: How do target the exact object I clicked on?

Comment: Target how and from where